# htaccess rewrite working but not all rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

These are my rules in .htacces file.

```
Options -MultiViews

# Turn Rewrite Engine On
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite for login.php
RewriteRule ^Login login.php [NC,L]

# Rewrite for myaccount.php
RewriteRule ^Myaccount myaccount.php [NC,L]

# Rewrite for index.php
RewriteRule ^Home index.php [NC,L]    

# Rewrite for post-images.php?post=xxxx
 RewriteRule ^Postimages/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) post-images.php?post=$1 [NC,L]
```

All rules are working fine but the last one. post-images.php pages is perfectly working if i directly use the url but not with rewriteurl. its showing

Not Found

The requested URL /PostImages/135 was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: This question is not related to PHP

Comment: rewrite rule was working perfectly with my previous server. Now after i move my working script to new server its not working properly. So i want to know if this is because of php version or something.. that's y i mentioned php keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Mmh, I tried to edit your RewriteRule and edited it to make this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^Postimages/(.*)$ http://www.yourwebsite.com/post-images.php?post=$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works for me, would u mind trying it?